# dropdown with repeated data angular

Tags: angular, typescript, web

Hello I have a dropdown that is used as a filter and it turns out that in the options that it shows me all the data and therefore are repeated, what I want is that if two data have the same name that only appears once. As shown in the picture I only want to appear once renatta and once exequiel. The filter performs well, but I need to have no repeated data.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V0Rgx.png)

in the code the first part of the ts I have it inside a function loadData(). HTML

```
<mat-form-field appearance="legacy">
<mat-label> <mat-icon>search</mat-icon> Buscar por usuario</mat-label>
<mat-select matNativeControl [(ngModel)]="person">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let current of persons" [value]="current" (click)="filter()">
        {{current}}
    </mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

TS

```
this.currentHistory.forEach((element: any) => {
  if (element.registerBy in this.persons) {
  } else {
    this.persons.push(element.registerBy)
  }
});

filter() {
    this.currentHistory = this.history.filter((current: any) => current.registerBy === this.person)
  }
```

Comment: What do you mean by group? The question is unclear, please provide information on what the desired outcome is.

Answer (score 0):

for excluding repeated names declare your `persons` list as [a Set](https://howtodoinjava.com/typescript/sets/).

```
persons = new Set<string>();
this.currentHistory.forEach((element: any) => {
  if (element.registerBy in this.persons) {
  } else {
    this.persons.add(element.registerBy)
  }
});
```

Comment: it worked for me, but for date fields would it be done the same way?